# Assembly reference exception on Server machine. Running fine on local

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have developed the project using Entity Framework 5. I created the object of the Entity class. It works fine on my local machine but when I am trying to run on my Server machine it gives me an error

> Compilation Error 
>   Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'DataExportSystemEntities' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 11:     public partial class Servers : System.Web.UI.Page
Line 12:     {
Line 13:         DataExportSystemEntities db = new DataExportSystemEntities();
Line 14:         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 15:         {
```

Entity framework dll is present in the bin folder.

Comment: How do you reference EF? Using NuGet? Have you tried Fusion Logger?

Comment: `DataExportSystemEntities` doesn't look like EF class. This is your own. Isn't it?

Comment: I am not sure I created a new model and the reference was added in the project.

Comment: When I added a Entity Data Model the class is created automatically Datamodel.Context.cs refers DataExportSystemEntities

Answer (score 1):

This is probably your assembly, built using Entity Framework. You've got a copy of it in your bin folder or something locally, but when you deploy it to the server the dll is missing.

I'd say make sure you've added a reference to your assembly that has the `DataExportSystemEntities` namespace in it (probably a project where you've implemented your data model using EF) to the project that gives you the error when you try to build the solution.

One way to track down what assembly has that `DataExportSystemEntities` class is to do a Find in Files search in every relevant solution you have and see where it's defined. The name really implies that it's something created for your data model. If the definition isn't found in your source code it's probably a 3rd party assembly that needs to get included in your deployment to the server.

Comment: "DataExportSystemEntities" is the class which implement the DbContext. It automatically generated when I add the "Entity Data Model".

Comment: I got the error in the same project where I created a Data model. It works fine locally but got the error on server machine.

Comment: So I'd first check the file system on the server to see if you can find the assembly where DataExportSystemEntities lives. If you can't find it there, you know it's not getting up to the server.

Comment: It is present in my project assembly. My project name is DataExportSystem and the DataExportSystem.dll is present on the server. Actually I copied the project folder from my local machine to the server and deploy it using IIS Manager